# Excel 2010 Conditional Formatting Based on Formula

Tags: excel, formatting, row, conditional-statements, cell

I am making a spreadsheet with values (part #s) arranged in ascending order in column B with other information corresponding to that part # in columns A-I. I am trying to use conditional formatting to color the cell and row if the value in B is greater than a certain value. I have tried tons of different ways and formulas to do this, but nothings has worked.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Select all of your data, e.g. A2:I1000 and use this formula in conditional formatting

`=$B2>100`

I used B2 because 2 is the first row of the data - if your data starts at a different row then you need to adjust accordingly. Change 100 to required value

$ is required before B to ensure that the whole row is formatted